# one-to-one and many-to-many relationship in datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have User and Project Model as shown below.

```
class User(db.Model):
    first_name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    last_name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    email_address = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class Project(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    time_required = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    manager = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name='project_manager')
    members = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

It's project management app.Some points

1. Each project can have only one manager(one-to-one)
2. one user can manage many project(one-to-many)
3. project can have many team-members. This can be done through
   ListProperty I think.

I don't know how to proceed, also I am new to datastore and database designing.

Comment: Is there something that isn't working as you expect? What happens when you try to use these models?

Comment: Yes, please clarify the question.